# Purpose of w:rPr versus w:pPr in OOXML (DOCX)?

Tags: xml, openxml, docx

I'm confused about Office Open XML architecture:  `w:rPr` tag doesn't seem to be working when inside of a `w:pPr` tag.

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00573C57" w:rsidRPr="004A77F9" w:rsidRDefault="00573C57" w:rsidP="006F57C5">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b />
            <w:sz w:val="36" />
            <w:szCs w:val="36" />
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004A77F9">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:b />
            <w:sz w:val="36" />
            <w:szCs w:val="36" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> BUSINESS</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004A77F9">
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> PLAN FILE</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

First `w:r` tag has a `w:rPr` tag which including bold (w:b) and font-size (w:sz) so section style taking bold and font-size style when docx outputting.

Last `w:r` tag hasn't `w:rPr` tag so this section has no style when docx outputting.

Then why `w:pPr` tag has `w:rPr` style when totally useless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOXML character properties can be applied at the paragraph (`w:p/w:pPr`) or run (`w:r/w:rPr`) levels.  Properties at the run level override those at the paragraph level.

In your particular example, there are currently no (general, but see note #2 below) paragraph-level properties and one run-level property, which is responsible for **BUSINESS** being bold.

**Notes:**

1. There's no guarantee that character properties will be normalized to a minimal representation for any given effect.
2. When a `w:rPr` element appears *within* a `w:pPr`,

   ```
   <w:pPr>
       <w:rPr>
           <w:b />
           <w:sz w:val="36" />
           <w:szCs w:val="36" />
       </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   ```

   it applies only to the paragraph glyph (¶).  (Yes, it's a rather esoteric feature.)  If you want to format the paragraph glyph, add properties there; if you do not particularly care about the paragraph glyph, you can remove the `w:pPr/w:rPr` wrapper and allow its properties to apply at the paragraph level:

   ```
   <w:pPr>
       <w:b />
       <w:sz w:val="36" />
       <w:szCs w:val="36" />
   </w:pPr>
   ```

Comment: When i'm adding <w:b /> tag inside of the w:rPr tag, "PLAN FILE" text outputting without bold. Bolding not used for this text. Also as i understand, you are saying "w:rPr tag isn't working when inside of w:pPr tag". So this tag completely useless when using inside of w:pPr tag.

Comment: *After* you fix the markup as shown in this answer, you have two options to make **PLAN FILE** bold: (1) Paragraph level: place `w:b` in the (repaired) `w:p/w:pPr` or (2) Run level: add a `w:rPr` to the run that contains "PLAN FILE" and place the `w:b` in ***this*** `w:rPr`.

Comment: I was coming across `rPr` inside `pPr` and Googled it expecting not to find any info, but happy to find your answer.   In Word 365 on Mac, the paragraph glyph is not formatted as you indicate, but great to know that this is a useless situation that can be ignored.