# how to hide a full paragraph in Word .docx file using python-docx

Tags: python-docx

Let's say I have a Word .docx document with just three paragraphs:

```
Visible
I want to hide this one
Visible
```

... and I want to hide the middle one, like this:

```
Visible
Visible
```

With MS-Word, I achieve this by simply selecting the whole middle paragraph (including end of paragraph mark), then going to font settings and selecting "hidden". This hides the full paragraph text, including the paragraph mark .

With [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Font.hidden) I was able to hide the text, but not the end of paragraph mark (so there is an unwanted line break between the two remaining visible paragraphs). This is my result:

```
Visible

Visible
```

This is my code:

```
def hiddenParagraphTest():
    from docx import Document
    d = Document()
    p = d.add_paragraph("Visible")
    p = d.add_paragraph()
    r = p.add_run()
    r.text = "Hidden"
    r.font.hidden = True
    p = d.add_paragraph("Visible")
    d.save("hiddenparagraphtest.docx")

hiddenParagraphTest()
```

I have the impression that this happens because the paragraph mark is not part of any runs.
So how should achieve this using python-docx?

Is there a .hidden attribute for the paragraphs somewhere? I couldn't find it in the documentation. I wonder if [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060173/710788) (not about python-docx) could be somehow related.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

PS: My sample code intends to generate a new document using python-docx ... but I think the same queston applies if I try to open a pre-existing .docx file in order to completely hide a certain paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Hide paragraph as you did in MS-Word and check the source xml, it looks like:

```xml
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:vanish/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:vanish/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Hidden</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Compared to your code generated docx, you should find that the additional `w:pPr` node, i.e., paragraph property, does the trick.

So, let's add this property manually.

```py
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement

def setHiddenProperty(p):
    pPr = OxmlElement('w:pPr') # paragraph property
    rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr') # run property
    v = OxmlElement('w:vanish') # hidden
    rPr.append(v)
    pPr.append(rPr)
    p._p.append(pPr)
```

Finally, apply it to your code.

```py
def hiddenParagraphTest():
    from docx import Document
    d = Document()
    p = d.add_paragraph("Visible")

    p = d.add_paragraph()
    setHiddenProperty(p)  # set paragraph hidden property
    r = p.add_run()
    r.text = "Hidden"
    r.font.hidden = True

    p = d.add_paragraph("Visible")
    d.save("hiddenparagraphtest.docx")

hiddenParagraphTest()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @skyway .  This really works. Now I wonder what happens when you use the paragraph hidden property BUT that paragraph's text is NOT hidden. What effect has the paragraph hidden property in that case? Nothing that I can see (the paragraph text is visible, and separate from the next paragraph ... as if nothing was hidden at all).

Comment: My Guess: the paragraph glyph `¶` itself will be hidden only if the entire paragraph (runs+¶) is hidden. This could be proved in MS-Word, say the paragraph "ABC¶": (1) hide ABC but not ¶, as you did in the beginning, -> ¶ is there; (2) hide ¶ but not ABC, as your new thought, -> ¶ is still there; (3) hide both ABC and ¶ -> ¶ is gone. (4) give an empty paragraph "¶", hide ¶ -> ¶ is gone!

Comment: Thanks @skyway  Can a paragraph be also unhidden with an equivalent code? Tell me if I should open a new question for this, since I can't figure it out. I don't see any code examples with `docx.oxml import OxmlElement` at [python-docx.readthedocs.io](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/). Could you edit your answer to link any relevant documentation sources? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @skyway: I dont understand your code. In setHiddenProperty(p), pPr is built but never used. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @quickbug thanks for pointing out this typo, the last line should be `p._p.append(pPr)`, as updated. Then why the previous code works? I guess xml is fault-tolerant, as <w:rPr><w:vanish/></w:rPr> indicates also a hidden paragraph.

Comment: Sorry skyway: I accepted this answer because the shown test worked. But this is creating a paragraph and hiding it before adding runs. For some reason, the function does not work correctly for me to hide an already existing paragraph. i.e. how to hide d.paragraphs[1] of an already existing document? (last line of my original question included that use case). Could you take a look at this test?: https://gist.github.com/abubelinha/54bb76457b7873aabb0991f061cd1720